# what does this abbreviation mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, abbreviations

What does this mean:

> a force 10 disaster area

it is taken from Mr. Bean Facebook page
?

In particular what means the number "10" there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a reference to the [Beaufort scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaufort_scale) of wind speeds. A force 10 gale is defined as "Storm, whole gale", i.e. a damaging and dangerous storm.

The Beaufort scale is specific to wind speeds, and not generally applied to other disasters, so the usage that you quote is metaphorical.